# How to order rows by value from another table

Tags: sql, db2

There is a table that has an empty column, I need to fill up this column using row_number() and order it by value from other table.
My CTE works but I can't update the second table.

This is CTE (it works)

`with testy(a, b, c) as (select t1.empno, t2.birthdate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t2.birthdate DESC) as order_by_id  from test_tab as t1 join employee as t2 on t2.empno = t1.empno)`

This request to update column but it doesn't work

```
with testy(a, b, c) as (select 
                           t1.empno
                           , t2.birthdate
                           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t2.birthdate DESC) as order_by_id  
                       from test_tab as t1 join employee as t2 on t2.empno = t1.empno)
update test_tab
set test_tab.id = testy.b
where test_tab.empno = testy.a
```

Comment: explain please what doesn't work mean?

Comment: you don't mention what variation or version of db2 you are using but most if not all do not support using a cte in a update or merge statement.  Here are a couple references that show how to do differently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582765/ibm-db2-9-7-common-table-expression-with-update  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57729426/in-db2-can-a-cte-be-used-in-the-table-expression-of-a-merge-or-update-statement  .  Look at the documentation for the variation/version you have for a definite answer.

Comment: It would be better if you edited the question providing your Db2 platform and version, some sample data in both tables and the desired `test_tab` contents after update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Db2 for LUW, then `UPDATE FROM SELECT` syntax is supported.
`MERGE` can be used otherwise.
Note, that your subselect MUST NOT contain duplicates by `EMPNO`.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TAB (EMPNO INT, ID INT);
INSERT INTO TEST_TAB (EMPNO) VALUES 10, 20;

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (EMPNO INT, BIRTHDATE DATE);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (EMPNO, BIRTHDATE)
VALUES
  (10, '1970-01-01'::DATE)
, (20, '1980-01-01'::DATE)

UPDATE TEST_TAB T
SET ID = E. order_by_id  
FROM 
(
select 
  t1.empno
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t2.birthdate DESC) as order_by_id  
from test_tab as t1 
join employee as t2 on t2.empno = t1.empno
) E
WHERE T.EMPNO = E.EMPNO;

SELECT * FROM TEST_TAB;
```

| EMPNO | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 2 |
| 20 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/exm0AyD0)

Comment: FWIW, it is possible to update a derived table without the need of FROM (assuming empno is unique in both tables). I added an example at: https://dbfiddle.uk/VfkWxkqS

Answer (score 0):

Your query should throw an error that indicates that testy.b is unknown

But you can do:

```
WITH testy (a, b, c) AS
(
    SELECT
        t1.empno,
        t2.birthdate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t2.birthdate DESC) AS order_by_id  
    FROM
        test_tab AS t1 
    JOIN
        employee AS t2 ON t2.empno = t1.empno
)
UPDATE test_tab
SET test_tab.id = (SELECT testy.b FROM testy 
                   WHERE test_tab.empno = testy.a)
```